# compare two times format HH:MM java-android

Tags: java, android

i try to compare two times , i parse'em then i used compareTo like :

```
        Date one = new Date();
        Date two = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", java.util.Locale.getDefault());

try {
                        two = sdf.parse("12:33");
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (one.compareTo(two) < 0) {
                         //do this
                    }
```

and when it doen't work : ( the condition is always 1 )
i tried to use this :

```
Date one = new Date();
        Date two = new Date();  
        boolean check = false;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
try {
                        two = sdf.parse("12:22");
                        check = two.after(one);
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(check)
                      // do this
                    }
```

the second code doesn't work at all , my up get crashes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `compareTo` . **compareTo()** method is defined in interface ***java.lang.Comparable*** .

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String getCurrentTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
String getTestTime="09:45";

if (getCurrentTime .compareTo(getTestTime) < 0)

{
   // Do your staff
 Log.d("Return","getTestTime less than getCurrentTime "); 
}
else
{
 Log.d("Return","getTestTime older than getCurrentTime "); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change SimpleDateFormat like below...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Below are the patterns:

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
```

This will work....

**UpDate :**

look this way it's work..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date inTime = sdf.parse("11:00");
    Date outTime = sdf.parse("10:00");

    if(inTime.compareTo(outTime) > 0){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Out time should be greater than In time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: lool , how can i add that patterns ? no idea

Comment: lool  when you work with `24 hour` then you have used `HH` not `hh` becuase `hh` is use for `12 hour`.

Comment: still the same with compareTo , nothing changed :/

Comment: i used the code in the second replay , it worked , thanks for the hep too :*